# What is the derivative $f(x)=|x|^\frac{3}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the derivative of $f(x)=|x|^\frac{3}{2},\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$.

When $x>0$ it is fine but the problem is when $x\leq 0$.I was trying by the defintion of derivative but what is $|x|^\frac{3}{2}$ when $x<0$?

Comment: $|x| = -x$ for $x < 0$. So ...

Answer (score 0):

Some function can be defined in a piecewise manner for convinience when the given closed form can't be analyzed directly. (|x| can be split like how @Martin R says in the comments.

$$|x|^{\frac 32 } = \lbrace ^{x^{3/2} \ ; \ x>0} _{(-x)^{3/2} \ ; \ x\leq0}$$

Beyond this point, I think finding the Derivative wouldn't be a problem.

It's always better to check it though, at points where the piecewise definition switches between pieces. You may use Defenition of Differentiability and check and you'll end up with $f'(0) = 0$

You can also generalize that
$$ \frac {df(|x|)}{dx} = \frac {df(|x|)}{d|x|} \cdot \frac {d|x|}{dx} \ ; \ x \neq 0$$

Comment: when $x\leq 0$ you said $-x^\frac{3}{2}$ not $(-x)^\frac{3}{2}$.Then suppose how can you find $|-1|^\frac{3}{2}$?

Comment: Edited, Sorry !

Answer (score 0):

$x<0$ being not permissible a real derivative is:

$$\dfrac 32 \sqrt{x}$$